# Display text between node

Tags: php, xml, xslt

Hi i have this xml structure with text between my tag :

```
<content>
    <line>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr<link>3</link></line>
</content>
<content>
    <line>hendrerit in vulputate velit esse</line>
</content>
<content>
    <line><bold>iriure dolor</bold>in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat</line>
</content>
```

I need to get this result :

```
<p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr<a href=''>3</a></span>
</p>
<p>
    <span>hendrerit in vulputate velit esse</span>
</p>
<p>
    <span><b>iriure dolor</b>in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat</span>
</p>
```

But i get this result :

```
<p>
    <span><a href=''>3</a></span>
</p>
<p>
    <span>hendrerit in vulputate velit esse</span>
</p>
<p>
    <span><b>iriure dolor</b></span>
</p>
```

how do I do?

Comment: "I can't seem to get" is not very telling. Please describe exactly what you have tried and what went wrong. Also, post your code and well-formed XML samples for input and output. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use str_replace? It looks like you are just changing content> to p>, line> to span>, and bold> to b>.

Comment: sorry, I mean to say, I get this result :
    <p>
        <span><a href=''>3</a></span>
    </p>
    <p>
    <span>hendrerit in vulputate velit esse</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span><b>iriure dolor</b></span>
    </p>

Comment: i don't use str_replace, i need to use xslt

Comment: "*But i get this result :*"  You get this result using what? We need to see your code in order to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Post your PHP code for better support. You could use `preg_match` and `DOMDocument` for this. But we need the PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a stylesheet that produces the output you need. It is impossible to say whether this is of any use to you because you did not say whether your attempted solution uses PHP or simply invokes an XSLT stylesheet.

Your input XML is not well-formed, the stylesheet assumes this input:

**Input XML**

```
<root>
    <content>
    <line>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr<link>3</link></line>
</content>
<content>
    <line>hendrerit in vulputate velit esse</line>
</content>
<content>
    <line><bold>iriure dolor</bold>in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat</line>
</content>
</root>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="content">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="line">
        <span>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="link">
        <a href="">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bold">
        <b>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </b>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <p>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr<a href="">3</a>
      </span>
   </p>
   <p>
      <span>hendrerit in vulputate velit esse</span>
   </p>
   <p>
      <span>
         <b>iriure dolor</b>in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat</span>
   </p>
</root>
```